# Get list of bindings for RabbitMQ

Tags: java, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

We have a RabbitMQ Broker (V3.5.7) which is routing messages to a group of servers.  When a server instance comes up (perhaps after a restart), I would like get a list of the current bindings for that server, so that I can confirm the bindings.  The server is running Java, so that would be the preferred API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an http call, something like that:

```java
 HttpURLConnection connection = null;

        try {
            //Create connection
            URL url = new URL("http://localhost:15672/api/exchanges/%2F/topic_test/bindings/source");
             connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
            String userpass =   "guest:guest";
            String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(userpass.getBytes()));
            connection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);

            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);



            //Get Response
            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder(); // or StringBuffer if Java version 5+
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
                response.append('\r');
            }
            rd.close();

            System.out.println(response.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }
```

maybe there are more efficient ways, but this is the idea

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer!  This will work perfectly!

Comment: Is there a way without doing an http call ? Something that would work with https ? Many thanks !

Comment: You can enable the SSL and execute the call in https:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html